# Spring Batch: Read chunksize during runtime

Tags: java, spring-batch

I have configured a batch job with one step of chunk size 10. Is it possible to read the chunksize during runtime?

As an example I have implemented the following ChunkListener to illustrate my issue:

```
public class MyChunkListener implements ChunkListener {

private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

private long startTimeInMs;

@Override
public void beforeChunk(ChunkContext context) {
    startTimeInMs = System.currentTimeMillis();
}

@Override
public void afterChunk(ChunkContext context) {
    long duration = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTimeInMs;
    long chunkSize = 10;
    logger.info(String.format(
            "Chunk of size %s computed in %sms", chunkSize, duration));
```

Is it possible to access the chunksize in the afterChunk method dynamically? I want to do something like

```
long chunkSize = context.getChunkSize();
```

### Update

The solution proposed by Joe Chiavaroli works fine for my case: Just inject the chunksize in the BatchConfig and the pass it to the ChunkListener by constructor argument:

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class MyBatchConfig {

    @Value("${batch.mystep.chunksize}")
    private int chunkSize;

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobs;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory steps;

    @Bean
    protected Step step(MyReader reader, MyProcessor processor, MyWriter writer) {
        return steps.get("myStep")
                .<InputItem, ProcessedItem> chunk(chunkSize)
                .reader(reader)
                .processor(processor)
                .writer(writer)
                .listener(new MyChunkListener(chunkSize))
                .build();
```

Comment: How are you setting the chunkSize on your step in the first place?  If you have it configured in your .properties or .yml you can grab it with `@Value` or you can pass it in via constructor or setter method on your listener.

Comment: @JoeChiavaroli : Thank you for your reply. I updated the question with your approach to set the chunksize via constructor argument, which works fine for me. I was searching for a class / method which I can call to access the chunksize at runtime and didn't thought about the other way round of setting the chunksize directly.